# Clean-up options for Ubuntu (13.10)

Tags: cleanup

I am looking for good tools that can be used to get rid of useless clutter of the system. Note that I'm not talking about deleting useless things, that I can manually do.

I am looking for tools like defragmenters, disk cleaners, those tools that delete duplicate files, those that can remove cache and useless application data, etc. Neither am I looking for a single tool that does this all, but I think my most gripes can be combined and a most of three tools will do the job.

The tag cleanup has this:
... removing temporary, unnecessary, redundant files or libraries; also ... cleaning the cache, logs, etc.

Comment: Have you tried Bleachbit.

Comment: I have not tried anything.

Answer (score 0):

Bleachbit is the windows equivalent of Ccleaner.

And in case of Disk defragmentation, it is completely unnecessary as ext filesystem doesn't defrag data like NTFS. For more details please visit this wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Defragmentation